# Functions using Non English based character sets

Tags: t-sql, function, cjk

I have a function that basically strips numerics out of a selection.  This function works great on English based character sets.  I have a new set of data that is comprised of non-English characters (Chinese, Japanese, Indian etc.), and I am not getting the desired effect.  I am using the `NVarchar` set to store any records that could be non-English.  Below is the function that I am currently using.  Any advice would be really helpful.

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[StripVenName]    Script Date: 05/03/2012 16:24:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StripVenName] (@InString as VarChar(8000))                           
RETURNS NVarChar(100) AS                            
BEGIN                           
    Declare @ReturnVal as NVarchar(4000)                        
    Declare @OutString as NVarchar(4000)                        
    Declare @Pos as smallint                        
    Declare @CurChar as NVarChar(1)                     

    IF LEN(@InString) = 0                       
        SET @ReturnVal = ''                 
    ELSE                        
    BEGIN                       
        Set @Pos = 1                    
        SET @OutString = ' '                    
        WHILE (@Pos <= Len(@InString))                  
        BEGIN                   
            Set @CurChar =  SUBSTRING(@InString, @Pos, 1)               
            if ASCII(@CurChar) between 65 and 90 or ASCII(@CurChar) between 97 and 122              
                SET @OutString = @OutString +   @CurChar            
            Set @Pos = @Pos + 1             
        END                 

        if len(@OutString) = 0                  
            SET @OutString = @InString              
        SET @ReturnVal = LTRIM(RTRIM(@OutString))                   
    END                     
RETURN @ReturnVal                           

END
```

Comment: Please add [tags] to your question (at least the language)

Comment: Looks like your input parameter is varchar instead of nvarchar.

Comment: G Mastros  Good catch.  That seems to have worked.  I can't believe I did not see that. it must be getting late in the day.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog about this several years ago.  The blog explains how to remove letters, but you want to remove numbers.  Please see the blog for a full explanation [SQL Server Extracting Data](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-extracting-data-again)

Your code can be reduced to this (and it will also perform better).

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNumericCharacters](@Temp NVarChar(1000))
Returns NVarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    While PatIndex(N'%[0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(N'%[0-9]%', @Temp), 1, N'')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you for the help.  I will be sure to check out your blog. and I am also going to use your code. thanks again.